# Область видимости переменной, внутри функции

Tags: php

Не понимаю, почему не видит переменную $a, если я указал, что она глобальная, значит должна взяться из области видимости функции inFoo?

Как тогда к ней обратиться?

```
function inFoo() {
    $a = 5;

    function foo() {
        global $a;
        return $a;
    }
    return foo();

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(inFoo());
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать замыкание надо и `use`:

```
function inFoo() {
    $a = 5;

    $inner = function() use ($a) {            
        return $a;
    };

    return $inner();
}
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Спасибо за способ, я сделал, передал параметром переменную a